# ParseDate Unparseable

Tags: java, date, exception, unparseable

I have Strings representing dates with the format `2014-11-01T18:57:24.497Z` which I want to parse 
as `SimpleDateFormat`.

I am using the following code

```
// 2014-11-01T18:57:24.497Z
SimpleDateFormat startAnalyzing = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz");
Date start = startAnalyzing.parse(startDateAnalyzing);
```

When doing this I am getting an exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2014-11-01T18:57:24.497Z"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
    ...
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you are trying to parse a `z` with `Z` so either choose `z` lower or upper for both (the String and the pattern).

Secondly, you need to "escape" the Z in the pattern (or z).

```
String startDateAnalyzing = "2014-11-01T18:57:24.497z";
SimpleDateFormat startAnalyzing = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'z'");
```

Output:

```
Sat Nov 01 18:57:24 CET 2014
```